# MEAN - router.get method is not triggering

Tags: angular, express, mongoose, mean

My requirement is pretty straightforward. I am trying to load a configurable `angular component` if configuration is not done yet. I have been trying to send a get request to server to find out a record already exists - if exists it would redirect to other `angular component` or keep in current `angular component` to configure.

I configured my `express` application for router in the following way -

```
const admin_routes = require('./server/routes/admin');
const configure_routes = require('./server/routes/configure');

app.use(mongooseExpressErrorHandler);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/product-bot')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server/images'));

app.use('/admin', admin_routes);
app.use('/configure', configure_routes);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/products/index.html'));
});

app.post('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/products/index.html'));
});
```

Here is the router -

```
const express       = require('express');;
const configureController = require('../controller/configure/configure');
const router        = express.Router();

router.get('/configure', configureController.check_super_admin_exists);
```

Here is my controller code -

```
exports.check_super_admin_exists = function(req, res, next) {
  let find_super_admin_promise = userModel.find_user_by_role();

  find_super_admin_promise.then(function(result) {

    if (typeof result === 'undefined' || result === null) {
      res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500);
    res.json('error');
  });
}
```

`userModel.find_user_by_role()` is working fine as I already use the model code in another feature.

But the problem is - I see my router code (`router.get('/configure', configureController.check_super_admin_exists)`) is never being executed. I have been working with `router.post()` method in the same project and it works fine.

Can you please help me with finding out what is the issue with my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for my observation, i think its because of the route you had initialize on your express application.

Example:

On you **index.js / server.js**, you had specified this line:

```
app.use('/configure', configure_routes);
```

But then on your **other file that sets up your /configure child routes**, you had specified that a route will have a name same as from your parent *(app.use('/configure', configure_routes))*

```
router.get('/configure', configureController.check_super_admin_exists);
```

With this, you may be able to access the configure route with:

```
/configure/configure       

or

http://localhost:3000/configure/configure     // if you're running at port 3000
```

---

To have it accessed as `/configure` or `http://localhost:3000/configure`, you need to edit your route configuration on your other file to just **'/'**

```
router.get('/', configureController.check_super_admin_exists);

// This way, it will follow the parent's name setup from index / server.js
// app.use('/configure', configure_routes);
```

---

> Express Sample Routes Structure:

```
STRUCTURE           ROUTES                             API URL

/user        app.use('/user', userRoutes)            
   /         router.get('/', getUser);               GET     /user
   /         router.post('/', saveUser);             POST    /user
   /:id      router.put('/:id', updateUser);         PUT     /user/:id
   /:id      router.delete('/:id', deleteUser);      DELETE  /user/:id
```

Comment: definitely one of the most confusing things about express 4 or whatever